# Using an integrating factor to solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been simply asked to integrate the following:
$dc/dt = 1-c-a c$.

I have used the integrating factor as $e^{(1+a) t}$.

Then finish with $c=1/(1+a)$, however my lecturer gets $c=\frac{1}{1+a}(1-e^{(a+1)t})$.

Could anyone at all show me the method to get this. I know it is meant to be a relatively easy question, but  i just don't know  what i am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Separate variables.

Comment: Is $e$ a constant or a function of $(1 + a) t$?

Comment: Is $*$ a convolution?  (Only computer languages use $*$ for multiply.)

Comment: sorry when i typed it the computer changed things, * is just multiplication. When i use the method of an integrating factor, my integrating factor is exp((1+a)t), so not e the constant. I thought i couldn't use separation of variables for this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think integrating factors are needed here.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
t
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}c}{1-(a+1)c}\\
&=-\frac{1}{a+1}\log(1-(a+1)c)+t_0\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Solving $(1)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
c
&=\frac{1}{a+1}\left(1-e^{-(a+1)(t-t_0)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{a+1}-\left(\frac{1}{a+1}-c_0\right)e^{-(a+1)t}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$c=\dfrac{1}{a+1}$ is a particular solution of $(2)$ with $c_0=\frac{1}{a+1}$ ($t_0=-\infty$),

Comment: ahhhhh thank you, in yours you have $t-t_o$ whereas he just has t, are you allowed to just put t there?

Comment: @R.M: $t_0$ is the constant of integration. It can be anything, $0$ is fine. Since we could have written $e^{-(a+1)(t-t_0)}=Ce^{-(a+1)t}$, we could set $C=0$ which would be the same as setting $t_0=-\infty$; this is why $t_0=-\infty$ is valid.

Comment: @R.M you can determine the explicit value of $t_0$ if you are given an initial condition for your problem.  Presumably, your lecturer used $c(0) = 0$ to conclude that $t_0 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!!!!

Answer (score 5):

$$
\frac{dc}{dt}+(1+a)c = 1
$$
multiply by integrating factor $e^{(1+a)t}$:
$$\begin{align}
&e^{(1+a)t}\frac{dc}{dt}+(1+a)e^{(1+a)t}c=e^{(1+a)t}
\\
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{(1+a)t}c\right)=e^{(1+a)t}
\\
&e^{(1+a)t}c = \int e^{(1+a)t}\,dt = \frac{e^{(1+a)t}}{1+a}+A
\\
&c = \frac{1}{1+a}+Ae^{-(1+a)t}
\end{align}$$
for some constant $A$.  Presumably there is an initial condition (that R.M. has not told us) to let the lecturer determine the constant $A$

Comment: no we aren't given any IC's either which is why i'm so confused by it all. but thanks so much!!!

Comment: Although I was able to solve this without integrating factors, if the right side of your first equation were not a function of $c$, an integrating factor would most likely be necessary. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

what @robjohn said is true:

because of the nature of this equation it is separable so an integrating factor is not strictly necessary. but because you requested it be done in that method:

first consider the form of the equation for an integrating factor: 
A differential equation of the form $y' + P(x)y = Q(x) $ can be solved by
 
$ y = \frac{\int{\mu Q(x)} dx}{\mu} + \frac{k}{\mu} $ where $k$ is an arbitrary constant and $\mu $ is the integrating factor ($\mu = e^{\int{P(x)}dx}$)

Let's fit your equation into the form needed for the method of integrating factors (In your case, $y$ is $c$ ):

$ c' + c(1+a) = 1 $

so you should obtain for an integrating factor of $ \mu = e^{\int{(1+a)}dt} = e^{t(1+a)} $

so $ c = \frac{1}{e^{t(1+a)}} \int{(e^{t(1+a)})dt} + \frac{k}{e^{t(1+a)}}$

if you integrated correctly, you should get $\int{(e^{t(1+a)})dt} = \frac{1}{1+a}e^{t(1+a)}$ which you will find nicely cancels with the integrating factor, $\mu$ which is already in the denominator. So your final answer should be

$ c = \frac{1}{1+a} + \frac{k}{e^{t(1+a)}} = \frac{1}{1+a} + ke^{-t(1+a)} $